# How can I use the computer name in this situation?

Tags: windows-7, networking, hosts, windows-xp-mode

I have the following scenario:

Windows 7 64-bit, hosting an XP Mode, on the host machine there is Oracle 10g installed.
On the XP Mode there is Oracle Client installed.

From XP Mode I am able to connect to Oracle on the host machine using its IP ONLY.

Example:

```
sqlplus username/password@12.12.12.12
```

However I need to connect to that Oracle instance using the NAME of the host machine. How do I do that? What settings should I make?

i.e.

```
sqlplus username/password@HOST_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got another solution.

I added the couple - ip address, host name in Windows' **hosts** file, then on I could use the host name.

Answer (score 1):

You would need some type of local DNS setup to make this work. If the computers join a windows domain and the domain controller is setup as a DNS server ( the normal case ) this would work "out of the box". Your router may have the option for local DNS otherwise you will have to setup your own DNS solution.

Comment: ok, thank you really it puts some light on the ussue. I think the general overview is more complicated - I'm in a VPN.

Comment: If you only need to resolve the name on the win 7 system and the XP guest IP does not change you could put an entry in the win 7 systems host file.

Comment: That's a lovely idea! I'll try it right away! ...but is it going to have effects when I try to connect from XPMode to the host machine?

Comment: You would have to do the same in reverse for the XP guest

Comment: Windows has included a local name resolution service (NetBIOS) ever since version 3.11. DNS is not required for simple usage (although highly recommended on production environments).